# How to set the starting number for filenames on a SD card with a Sony camera?

Tags: memory-card, sony, sdcard, filenames

I have a sony HX-series pocket camera. For some reason, the file numbering of videos (and not of still photos) got reset recently and started from zero. This is causing me a nightmare of filename collisions with old videos.

I'm using the AVCHD format, so the files get saved in a very different directory structure on the sd card than ordinary mp4 videos.

How can I get the camera to continue from a certain number for the video filenames?

Comment: Note on why I downvoted: I vote video questions down because this is a photography site.

Comment: 1. Not to mention using the evil silicon based photo sensor rather than photo reactive metal halides. 2. As this question relates to writing file numbers with a camera capable of video and still photos it would seem to be frmes per image agnostic.

Comment: What is the exact model number AND did my suggestion work for you?

Comment: Hi @RussellMcMahon. My model is HX30V. I'll check your suggestion and report back.

Comment: See [manual page here](http://esupport.sony.com/docs/dvimag/DSCHX20V_HX30_HX30V_guide/en/contents/06/05/06/06.html) which says "Starts from 0001 each time the folder is changed. (When the recording folder contains a file, a number one higher than the largest number is assigned.)" - which is what I suggested - and may even work :-).

Comment: @mattdm et al - As this relates to use of camera equipment, and as the equipment, and as [the camera concerned is primarly a "stills" camera with video added](http://store.sony.com/wcsstore/SonyStyleStorefrontAssetStore/img/718x407/DSCHX20VB.png), and as the issue applies as much to a still image as to a video image AND as many questions related to specific camera equipment seems to jump the required hurdle for acceptability why does this one not?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon - The lines will only be blurred more with time. I would highly recommend if you or the poster want questions like this to be kept open, that having "video" in the title and notes about video file extensions in the question would be things you would want to change. Make it on topic by switching the word "photo" or .JPEG, might be what you want.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon But note that the stills filenames are working fine. This is entirely about the numbering of the video files.

Comment: @mattdm - It's subtle, or may be :-). The two numbering schemes work independently, or may do. If you juggle the card  in/out, power on/off, cards with just stills / just videos / stills & videos, etc arrangements you can get it to set/not set files numbers to track either a master sequence OR an independent sequence on two cards.  This can be devastating and does happen. Ask me how I know :-) :-(. If you have two such arcaneries working together one may get reset to zero, or lock their numbering sequences to a newly inserted card that has only video or only stills on it or ... .

Comment: @mattdm ... GJ trying my solution is the easiest test. I expect it to work :-). I may be wrong. I don't know how other manufacturers handle this. Imre mentions renaming the file "on the spot". I don't know if he means "in camera, stand alone" which is a good trick if your camera can do it. If you do it in camera over eg USB connection there is a possibility of the camera file system doing something clever. Even my suggested method would ideally have a format between download and upload. But, just rename will probably work.

Comment: @dpollitt - I have no 'axe to grind' re video files or capability. My DSLRs video capability gets used a vanishingly small percent of its total usage (not quite zero). I usually carry a Sanyo XACTI (or two) in my pocket for when video is liable to be useful. It;s just that this is a hardware and firmware related feature which will have impact on others for both stills and video.

Answer (score 0):

How many numbers off are we talking?  If you have 100 old videos, one way might be to create some dummy files to conflict with the current file number.  I don't know the naming convention, but lets say DSCN0001.MTS, DSCN0002.MTS through DSCN0100.MTS.  Place those on the SD card and then shoot a video.  It should then bump up the counter to DSCN0101.MTS.

The dummy files just need be 1 byte text files renamed to *.MTS.

Do a test: if it currently has a sequence of 17, then create dummy files for 17, 18, 19, 20 and see if it doesn't create the next video at 21.

Answer (score 0):

*Added at top:*

Mar 18 advises that the camera is a Sony HX30V, which shares a manual with the HX20V and HX30.

A [HX20 / HX20V / HX30V user guide is available here](http://esupport.sony.com/docs/dvimag/DSCHX20V_HX30_HX30V_guide/en/index.html)

On [this page](http://esupport.sony.com/docs/dvimag/DSCHX20V_HX30_HX30V_guide/en/contents/06/05/06/06.html) under "File number" it says

- "Starts from 0001 each time the folder is changed.
  When the recording folder contains a file,
  a number one higher than the largest number is assigned."

Which is what I suggested  (below) - and may even work :-).

---

Many Sony cameras can be persuaded to pick up on an existing file name sequence by turning them off, inserting a memory card with a photo on it with a number in the desired sequence, and then turning the camera on. Starting with a new folder MAY help.

Try this.

- Format a memory card.
- If you do not have a new video folder and a new still image folder, use "new folder' which should create a pair of folders.
- Take a few seconds of video.
- Turn camera off. Take out card. Download video file. Rename to desired name. Rewrite to card. Ensure old version is absent. Reinsert card.
- Turn camera on.
- Take short video. Check file names.
- Tear out hair or cheer.
- Report

Comment: Deer all no-ing downvoter. The infermayshin in this answer is either correct or incorrect. The information in the Sony manual for the camera concerned adumbrates (look it up) that it's correct, and general Sony practice is to do as I described previously. If it's correct you should probably be reading the guidelines for up of down voting, either yet again or for the first time. If you KNOW that it's incorrect then it would be a rolly good idea fer you to tell us so. No?

Comment: At least for my Pentax cameras, this trick works. I suppose it'd be easier to rename the file on spot instead of download>rename>upload.

Comment: I had the same idea, but yours is a huge advantage in that you don't have to create all the other lesser-number files as well - it just picks the largest one anyway and increments.